# how to add price with decimal points in postman automation

Tags: automation, request, postman

how to add a price in the postman automation request body. should pass the value with two decimal points

price=5.77

Is this the correct way? Following is the request body or postman automation.

`{ "price"=[{{price}}] }`

Answer (score 1):

I would just set the value in the pre-request script and use javascript to format the value however you want. Do this at the collection level if you want to use it in multiple requests. You can even create some global utils so that you can selectively reset that value.

In your collection pre-request script do something like:

```js
postman.setGlobalVariable("loadUtils", function loadUtils() {

    utils.getRandomDollarAmount = function getRandomDollarAmount() {
        var precision = 100; // 2 decimals
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 * precision - 1 * precision) + 1 * precision) / (1*precision);  
    }

    return utils;
} + '; loadUtils();');
```

Then in the pre-request script for any request you want to get a new dollar amount:

```js
var utils = eval(globals.loadUtils);
const { Property } = require('postman-collection');
pm.environment.set("randomDollarAmount", utils.getRandomDollarAmount());
```

Then use it in your actual request body:

```json
{ 
  "price"=[{{randomDollarAmount}}]
}
```